# Meteor Blaze Bind to Dynamic Variable in Loop

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have two stores: Students and Assignments.  Each assignment document contains student grades:

```
{
  _id: 'assignment_id_here',
  name: 'Homework Assignment 1',
  grades: {
    'id_of_student_1': 88,
    'id_of_student_2': 93,
    'id_of_student_7': 76
  }
}
```

My template has access to students documents and the assignments.  I want to display the grades for each student (which are 88,93 and 76 above).

```
<div>Assignment Name: {{assignment.name}}</div>
<div>Grades</div>
{{#each students}}
  Student {{name}} with student ID {{_id}} received {{assignment.grades[_id]}} on this assignment
{{/each}}
```

`assignment.grades[_id]` Does not work!  What will work?  Is there a better way to structure the documents seen here?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to structure your documents is to adopt this schema which puts the students grades as an array of embedded documents:

```
{
    _id: 'assignment_id_here',
    name: 'Homework Assignment 1',
    grades: [
        {
            _id: 'id_of_student_1',             
            grade: 88
        },
        {
            _id: 'id_of_student_2',             
            grade: 93
        },
        {
            _id: 'id_of_student_3',             
            grade: 76
        }
    ]    
}
```

which you can then use Handlebars helpers for displaying the embedded documents. The following example demonstrates this (untested):

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <title>Assignment Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> course}}
</body>

<template name="course">
    <ul>
    {{#each assignments}}
        <li>
            <p>Assignment Name: {{name}}</p>
            <p>Grades:
                {{#display}}    
                    <li>Name : {{name}}</li>
                    <li>Grade : {{grade}}</li>
                {{/display}}
            </p>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
Assignments = new Meteor.Collection("assignments");
Students = new Meteor.Collection("students");

if (Meteor.isClient) {  
    Handlebars.registerHelper('display', function(context, options) {
        var el = "<ul>";
        for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
            var student = Students.findOne({ "_id": context[i] }),
                assignment = Assignments.findOne(
                   { "grades._id": context[i] }, 
                   { "grades": { 
                       $elemMatch: { _id: context[i] } 
                      } 
                   });
            if (student && assignment){
                el += options.fn({name: student.name, grade: assignment.grades[0].grade});
            }
        }
        el += "</ul>"
        return el;
    });

    Template.course.assignments = function(){
        return Assignments.find({});
    }

    var student_one   = Students.insert({ name: "Student1" }),
        student_two   = Students.insert({ name: "Student1" }),
        student_seven = Students.insert({ name: "Student7" }),
        one     = { _id: student_one, grade: 88 },
        two     = { _id: student_two, grade: 93 },
        seven   = { _id: student_seven, grade: 76 });

    Assignments.insert({
        name: "Homework Assignment 1",
        grades: [one, two, three]
    }); 
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm curious, why would it be better to place the grades on the student rather than the assignment?  I don't think I'd be able to get rid of the Assignments collection, because there is some information unique to each assignment which would not fit in the students collection.  Also, my use cases require me to iterate over assignment documents at times.

Comment: @Dave After some serious thought I think you are right, it's indeed better to embed documents with just the grades and the respective student ids in the Assignments collection, let me update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

You can write a helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('getGrade', function (student) {
  return this.data.assignment.grades[student]
})
```

Or put grades into the student's documents

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm having trouble constructing a call to getGrade.  First, the "this" variable is bound directly to the student in the loop, so this._id gives me the student ID.  Since the student is passed to the function implicitly, how can I pass the assignment?